# Data Binding with json C# windows phone 7

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to solve a problem that I have couple of days now.
I am building a windows mobile app (C# silverlight for windows phone NET FRAMEWORK 4)

I am sending a Http Request to a web service. I get my json respond, which looks like this:

```
[{"rows":"","name":"something1","city":"mycity","phone":"1231233856"},{"rows":"","name":"something1","city":"mycity","phone":"1231233856"},{"rows":"","name":"something1","city":"mycity","phone":"1231233856"}]
```

I also have this class in my project:

```
public class ProfileOptions
{
  public string name { get; set; }
  public string address { get; set; }
  public string city { get; set; }
  public string sum_points { get; set; }
}
```

Now, inside a function I am getting the **values** of this json and put them inside a List.

```
JSonReader jr = new JSonReader();
IJSonObject json = jr.ReadAsJSonObject(_result);

IEnumerable items = json.ArrayItems;
List<object> ListObject = new List<object>();
foreach (var arrayItem in json.ArrayItems)
{
     foreach (var objItem in arrayItem.ObjectItems)
     {
         ListObject.Add(objItem.Value);
         //MessageBox.Show(objItem.Value.ToString());
     }
 }
```

The MessageBox.Show(..), shows me correctly the values that I want (something,mycity....etc).
Next step is to check if the first value is 0, show me a Message, otherwise put these values in **Listbox binding the values**.

```
if (ListObject.ElementAt(0).ToString() == "0")
{
   MessageBox.Show(ListObject.ElementAt(2).ToString());
}
else
{
   ListBoxShops.ItemsSource = ListObject;
}
```

The xaml file is like this:

```
<Grid Name="ProfileGrid">
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Black" Background="#FFE74C3C" Opacity="0" IsEnabled="False" Width="455" Height="Auto" Name="LoginUserBtn" Content="Please login" BorderBrush="Black" Click="LoginUserBtn_Click" />
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Black" Background="#FFE74C3C" Opacity="0" IsEnabled="False" Width="455" Height="Auto" Name="FirstChenInBtn" Content="Go for your first check-in" BorderBrush="Black" Click="FirstChenInBtn_Click" />
<ListBox x:Name="ListBoxShops" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Height="540" Margin="0,65,0,0">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
         <!--<Canvas Width="50" Height="50" Name="IconProduct"></Canvas>-->
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Width="150" Height="100" Foreground="Black"></TextBlock>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding address}" Width="150" Height="100"></TextBlock>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding city}" Width="150" Height="100"></TextBlock>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding total_points}" Width="Auto" Height="100"></TextBlock>
             </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
</Grid>
```

I tried many things but without any results.. The weird thing is that I get no errors. The app is still running, but I can not see my values in the ListBox. Any help would be appreciated. thanks for your time

*By the way I'm using the Library of CodeTitans to accomplised this task

Comment: Use [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). A single line is enough `var ListObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ProfileOptions>>(yourjson);`

Comment: I tried to install this library at first through NuGet of VS 2010, but I couldn't. I am getting an error message that says:

"Successfully installed 'Newtonsoft.Json 7.0.1'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Newtonsoft.Json 7.0.1'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Could not install package 'Newtonsoft.Json 7.0.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'Silverlight,Version=v4.0,Profile=WindowsPhone71', but the package does not contain any assembly references that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author."

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer. Actually it was much simpler than I thougt.Anyway, if anyone interesting,

```
List<ProfileOptions> ListProfileOptions = new List<ProfileOptions>();
                for (int i = 0; i < json.Count; i++)
                {
                    ProfileOptions ProfileOptionsObj = new ProfileOptions();
                    ProfileOptionsObj.name = json[i][2].ToString();
                    ProfileOptionsObj.address = json[i][3].ToString();
                    ProfileOptionsObj.city = json[i][4].ToString();
                    ProfileOptionsObj.sum_points = json[i][5].ToString();
                    ListProfileOptions.Add(ProfileOptionsObj);
                }
                //insert into ListBox all the values
                ListBoxShops.ItemsSource = ListProfileOptions;
```